# Overriding the webBrowser click event

Tags: c#, winforms

I need some information about what happens when a user clicks a hyperlink in a webBrowser control. My thinking is that it calls the `.Navigate()` method, but I am not sure.

I have created a wrapper method that wraps around the navigate method. What I want to do is that when a user clicks a link, or a button or watever, my method is called instead of the `.Navigate()` method.

What do I need to ovverride to achieve this?

Thanks

Edit: It seems there is some trouble understanding my question, let me try to refrase:

I have created my own webBrowser control that inherits from WebBrowser. In my control, there is a method I use to navigate which does some steps before actually calling the navigate() method.

Now calling this method from my code is easy, just call my method instead of .Navigate. But what I want is that when a user clicks a link on a page my method runs instead of .Navigate.

Answer (score 9):

No need to override, just attach an event handler to every link on the page on the WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted event.

```
private bool bCancel = false;

private void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender,
                                 WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < webBrowser.Document.Links.Count; i++)
  {
     webBrowser.Document.Links[i].Click += new    
                            HtmlElementEventHandler(this.LinkClick);
  }
}
private void LinkClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  bCancel = true;
  MessageBox.Show("Link Was Clicked Navigation was Cancelled");
}
private void webBrowser_Navingating(object sender, 
                                WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e )
{
  if (bCancel == true)
  {
     e.Cancel=true;
     bCancel = false;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

If you would like to find more info about the link that was clicked simply modify the LinkClick event handler with something like this:

```
private void LinkClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElement element = ((HtmlElement)sender);
    string id = element.Id;
    string href = element.GetAttribute("href");

    bCancel = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Link Was Clicked Navigation was Cancelled");        
}
```

Comment: How can I tell which link was clicked this way? I want to show help to user, but if user clicks hyperlink it would be opened with real browser.

Comment: @Moonwalker I've updated my answer. You can find out everything about the link inside your LinkClick event handler, by casting the sender into an HtmlElement: ((HtmlElement)sender). Hope it helps.

Comment: This don't handle the case in which you are dynamically generating the content of your page (i.e. ajax request that fill a table)

Answer (score 5):

The Navigating event is raised.  You can implement an event handler for it to reject and redirect the navigation request:

```
    private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e) {
        // Redirect expertsexchange to stackoverflow
        if (e.Url.ToString().Contains("experts-exchange")) {
           e.Cancel = true;
           webBrowser1.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com");
        }
    }
```

Comment: So after this event, the normal flow would be for the WebBrowser to call the .Navigate method? I don't want this to happen, I want it to use my own method instead.

Comment: Well, set e.Cancel = true and call Navigate() yourself.  It's not very clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I updated the main question. I don't know why it's hard to understand, I want to call my own method instead of .Navigate. That's why I think its best to just override it.

Comment: You'll need to stop thinking that overriding Navigate() is possible.  And the user clicking links in a web page does not in any way go through Navigate(), that method is only callable from code.  The browser tells you the user clicked a link, that's what the Navigating *event* is for.

Comment: I see, so my best option would be to handle the navigating event and call my method from there, and then doing e.cancel to stop it from doing the usual flow.

Comment: Thank you so much! I could intercept certain links thanks to you!!

Comment: Thanks, this has help me

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, then you are going the wrong way.

Simply look at the HTML code of the hyperlink.
If its a simple link - then it simply goes to Navigate.
If there is some script function call, then you can see what the function does.

Comment: So if I override Navigate() all links clicked will go thru my method??

Comment: That is by far close to anything I said. I simply suggested examining the HTML code to understand the functionality behind it, as I understood you need.

Comment: If you actually need to run some code whenever the user clicks it, then you could use the browser.Document.Click event after the document is initialized (after each navigation), and the args to determine if the element clicked is your hyperlink, and running your own code as well.

Comment: Yes I need to run my own .Navigate method instead of the default one. Check my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

try doing it through Jquery

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    __doPostBack('functionForClick','');
});
```

Haven't tried this though.

Answer (score 0):

You are all over looking the event when a link is targeted to another window.

Suppose the link has target="_new", in this case, the navigating event is never fired, because it is a new webBrowser that actually opens the url.